# On loading module got JS error in jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

I am using  [Jquery form validation library](http://www.formvalidator.net/)

and I need to validate file input with that. 
My code is as follows:

```js
    $.validate({
        form : '#form',
        modules : 'file',
        validateOnBlur : false,
        borderColorOnError : 'red',
        inputParentClassOnError : 'error',
        scrollToTopOnError: false,
        errorMessageClass: 'text-error',

        onError : function() {

        },
        onSuccess: function($form) {
            // The input button is disabled if the form contains backend validations
            $form.find('input[type="submit"]').unbind('click');
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is when I try to load module file it gives me a JS error

> TypeError: a.formUtils is undefined" in file.js

I am unable to find out what the problem is.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thankyou.

Comment: What does file.js contain?

Comment: file.js contains the custom validators of file type like mime, size etc. I am not getting what is $.formUtils

Comment: I'm validating your code here https://jsfiddle.net/xm9ap1ku/, and it works

Comment: thanks @Jose Rojas. yes it works for simple text type input but does not work for file type input...

Comment: here there is a example with file https://jsfiddle.net/xm9ap1ku/1/